# Batch Script to Switch user to Admin

Tags: batch-file, dos

I need to login as different user to Windows and then switch user to Administrator user through batch script. RUNAS windows utility dint work for me. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 3):

`RunAs` does not work because in (I assume you are using) Windows 7 the administrative account disabled by default.

I've found the easiest way to start an elevated command prompt (even from a batch script) is to create an elevated short-cut.

```
First, Right-Click on your desktop and Click "New -> Shortcut"
Next type CMD into the box labled "Type the location of the item:"
Click "Next -> Finish"
```

You now have a new shortcut called `CMD.exe` on your desktop.  Next...

```
Right Click "CMD.exe -> Properties -> Advanced..."
Check "Run as administrator"
Click "OK -> OK"
```

Now you have a shortcut to `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` that will launch `cmd.exe` with administrative privilidges.  You can now move the shortcut anywhere you want to, just make sure that it's somewhere in the PATH variable, so you don't have to specify it's path when calling it. I have a special directory for batch files, and another for 3rd party executables. I move mine to the batch directory.

Now according to Windows, the name of the shortcut is cmd.exe, but if you drop into 'DOS', you will be able to see that it's **actually** named `cmd.exe.lnk`. I renamed mine to `cmd.Admin.lnk` just to specify what it does.

You can now start it several different ways.

Click the `START Ball`, and type: `cmd.exe.lnk`<kbd>Return</kbd> (or `cmd.admin.lnk`, whichever you chose).
Open a command prompt and type: `cmd.exe.lnk`<kbd>Return</kbd>
Add the line `cmd.exe.lnk` to a batch file.

You can even pass it parameters like:

```
cmd.admin.lnk "/c echo. & echo %time% & echo. & pause.exe"
cmd.admin.lnk "/c cd /d d:\tmp & x.bat & echo. & echo %time% & echo. & pause.exe"
cmd.admin.lnk "/c title The Shiznit & echo. & echo %date% %time% & echo. & pause.exe"
cmd.admin.lnk "/c title The Shiznit & echo. & echo %date% %time% & echo. & pause.exe & exit 999"
```

The last example will return an `%errorlevel%` of 999. Though no other variables will be passed back.

Notice how I have to put `.exe` after the internal command `pause`. I have found that you can force the execution of lots of internal commands this way. Even `.com` works.

Lastly, unlike `runas`, using this shortcut will do two things **:**

**First**, it will create a pop-up window asking for permission to execute with administrative privileges. This, like the default disabling of the Administrator account, is a security measure to prevent malicious programs and scripts from running.

**Second**, if launched from the command-prompt or a batch file, it will open **another** command-interpreter window.  Unless you launch it with `start`, the calling window waits for the new window to close, then continues execution of the batch file or command-interpreter where it left off.

Comment: Works well, except when a command requires a quoted string. I used: set "\quot="" then cmd.admin.lnk "/c echo.test>%\quot%some path with space%\quot%". This works, but is there an easier way? Note: using escapes: \", ^", and "" did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

CPAU.exe was a good workaround to resolve this issue